# Can't ping AWS RDS instance after allowing ICMP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, icmp

I'm trying to ping my newly set up AWS RDS instance, but I am unable to do so (four "Request timed out" errors).

I added a rule in my EC2 security group for the instance, allowing all ICMP but it still does not work.

I am new to this, so apologies if I'm missing something obvious. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amazon Relational Database Service (Amazon RDS) is a web service that makes it easy to set up, operate, and scale a relational database in the cloud.

With that said, it is not a host that you can ping. In fact many instances of the database product could reside on one virtual machine; the infrastructure behind this is hidden from user.

EC2 security group should work, for EC2 server; are you pinging the EC2 instance correctly? The security rule should be setup as the picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaW5M.png)

Comment: While it is true that RDS instances do not respond to pings, you are entirely incorrect to call RDS "a server that many databases reside on."  Each RDS instance runs in its own VM, no different than each EC2 instance, and each RDS instance has its own IP address. Also, the notion that responding to ICMP could severely impact other users' performance is unfounded speculation.

Comment: Yes you are right, the database is not a server. The impact of ping is trivial compared to other service.